# manipulando arquivo csv

Tags: python, csv

boa pessoal.
preciso usar um arquivo csv, que tem mais de dez colunas e duas mil linhas.
to com muita duvida de como pegar uma coluna isolada.
esse programa abaixo, peguei na internet.

```
separador = ','

with open('owid-covid-data.csv', 'r') as txt_file:
    for line_number, content in enumerate(txt_file):
        if line_number: 
            colunas = content.strip().split(separador)
            print(f"\nPaís: {colunas[2]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python possui uma lib `csv` que pode te ajudar, eu acho que é nativo e nem precisa instalar nada, só importar, com ela fica muito simples trabalhar com arquivos `csv`, vamos as explicações, para testar crie um arquivo para verificar as funcionalidade:

tt.csv (um teste bobo e sem noção lol)

```
Nome, nota, media, aprovado
ederwander, 5, 3, nao
thomas, 10, 8, sim
maria, 9, 7, sim
luiz, 0, 4, nao
joao, 6, 5, nao
fernanda, 2, 6, sim
```

Agora podemos demonstrar como é fácil pegar a coluna que deseja, repare que o arquivo possui delimitadores padrões separados por `,` e que possui 4 colunas, a primeira coluna começa com `0` a segunda coluna será a número `1` e assim sucessivamente ...

Então vamos fazer um exemplo simples só para pegar a última coluna a de número `3`:

```
import csv

with open('tt.csv') as csv_file:
    
    ler_csv = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    ler_csv.__next__()

    for coluna in ler_csv:
        #print( row[0] + ', ' + row[1] + ', ' + row[2] )
        print( coluna[3])
```

O exemplo acima vai imprimir a coluna 4:

```
C:\Python33>python.exe testcsv.py
 nao
 sim
 sim
 nao
 nao
 sim
```

veja no código o outro print de exemplo comentado, caso vc queira imprimir as outras colunas, acho que é isso, isso é o básico ...

Answer (score 0):

Python possui o pandas que é uma biblioteca muito útil, principalmente para manusear grandes arquivos. Exemplo:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Cria-se uma DataFrame para receber o arquivo
# Pode se passar mais parametros como a forma como o arquivo e separado, padrão é por virgula
df = pd.read_csv('nome_arquivo.csv')

# Você pode usar o proprio nome da coluna ao df, contudo se o nome tiver espacos, acentos usa-se colchetes
# Funcao value_counts ira contar os valores das diferentes aparições na coluna
var = df.Nome_Coluna.value_counts()
var2 = df['Nome Coluna'].value_counts()

# Voce pode buscar uma string especifica em uma coluna
palavra = df[df.Nome_Coluna.str.contains('palavra')]

# Pode agrupar a partir de 'palavra'
# size() = numero de entradas
# Voce tambem pode plotar graficos com plot()
palavra.groupby('Outra Coluna').size().plot(kind= 'barh')
```

Esse link me ajudou muito a utilizar essa biblioteca:
https://towardsdatascience.com/analysis-of-boston-crime-incident-open-data-using-pandas-5ff2fd6e3254